# Collision Problem Platform Game How To Fix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

My Problem is, is that when I Collide With my [Floor Square](https://gyazo.com/1c9737baaaface91ca06c34bb3ac5ceb) it constantly drops me down

> > I made a class floor: for it and defined it to floor1 and then drawed it onto my screen but I am still having the problem wont let me collide and stand on it just constantly falling

my collision

```
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(floor1.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.JumpCount = 10
                playerman.y = floor1.rect.top - playerman.height + 1
                if playerman.rect.right > floor1.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < floor1.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = floor1.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < floor1.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > floor1.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = floor1.rect.right
```

my full code

```
# import pygame moduee
import pygame
pygame.init()



# window
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("games")
bg = pygame.image.load("background_02.png")
left_image =  pygame.image.load("Sprite-0002.png")
right_image = pygame.image.load("Sprite-0003.png")
platforms = pygame.image.load("ok.png")
def DrawWindow():
    window.blit(bg, (0,0))

# player

class player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height  = height
        self.width = width
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 5
        self.fall = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.left_image = pygame.image.load("Sprite-0002.png")
        self.right_image = pygame.image.load("Sprite-0003.png")
        self.left_image = pygame.transform.scale(self.left_image,(self.left_image.get_width()*2,self.left_image.get_height()*2))
        self.right_image = pygame.transform.scale(self.right_image,(self.right_image.get_width()*2,self.right_image.get_height()*2))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,left_image.get_width(), left_image.get_height())
        self.direction = "Left" #set a stating direction

    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        if self.direction == "Left":
            window.blit(self.left_image,self.rect)
        else:
            window.blit(self.right_image,self.rect)


# enemy class
class enemy:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.platforms = pygame.image.load("ok.png")
        self.platforms = pygame.transform.scale(self.platforms,(self.platforms.get_width()*5,self.platforms.get_height()*5))

        self.rect = self.platforms.get_rect(topleft = (x, y)) # <---

        self.direction = "left" #set a stating direction
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.platforms,self.rect)




# coin class
class coin:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, self.rect)

# floor class

class floor:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, self.rect)



# FPS
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# colors
white = (255,255,255)
green = (0,255,0)
Yellow = (255, 255, 0)
Blue =  (0,255,216)

# define player and enemy class
playerman = player(40,390,30,30, Blue)
floor1 = floor(-9999,490,15000,50, white)
enemy1 = enemy(150,390,150,10, green)
enemy2 = enemy(300,320,150,10, green)
enemy3 = enemy(70,260,150,10, green)
enemies = [enemy1,enemy2,enemy3]


# define cooins
coin1 = coin(210,365,20,20, Yellow)
coin2 = coin(250,365,20,20, Yellow)
coin3 = coin(110,235,20,20, Yellow)
coin4 = coin(360,290,20,20, Yellow)
coin5 = coin(400,290,20,20, Yellow)
Coins_list = [coin1,coin2,coin3,coin4,coin5]
# font + display and eat coins and gain
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
score = 0
text = font.render('Score = ' + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.center = (100,40)


# main loop
runninggame = True
while runninggame:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runninggame = False


    DrawWindow()
    window.blit(text,textRect)
    for coin in Coins_list:
        coin.draw()
    for enemy in enemies:
        enemy.draw()
    floor1.draw()


    if playerman.y < 250:
        playerman.y += 1
        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.y += playerman.speed
        for coin in Coins_list:
            coin.y += playerman.speed

    if playerman.y > 450:
        playerman.y -= playerman.fall
        for enemy in enemies:
            enemy.y -= playerman.fall
        for coin in Coins_list:
            coin.y -= playerman.fall


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()



    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        playerman.direction = "Left"
        playerman.x -= playerman.speed

        if playerman.x < 100:
            playerman.x += playerman.speed
            for enemy in enemies:
                enemy.x += playerman.speed
            for coin in Coins_list:
                coin.x += playerman.speed





    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        playerman.direction = "Right"
        playerman.x += playerman.speed
        if playerman.x > 400:
            playerman.x -= playerman.speed
            for enemy in enemies:
                enemy.x -= playerman.speed
            for coin in Coins_list:
                coin.x -= playerman.speed



    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
        collide = False
        playerman.isJump = False
        for enemy in enemies:
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.JumpCount = 10
                playerman.y = enemy.rect.top - playerman.height + 1
                if playerman.rect.right > enemy.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < enemy.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = enemy.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < enemy.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > enemy.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = enemy.rect.right

            if playerman.rect.colliderect(floor1.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.JumpCount = 10
                playerman.y = floor1.rect.top - playerman.height + 1
                if playerman.rect.right > floor1.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < floor1.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = floor1.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < floor1.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > floor1.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = floor1.rect.right



            for i in range(len(Coins_list)-1,-1,-1):
                if playerman.rect.colliderect(Coins_list[i].rect):
                    del Coins_list[i]
                    score += 1
                    text = font.render('Score = ' + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
                    textRect = text.get_rect()
                    textRect.center = (100,40)



            if playerman.rect.bottom >= 500:
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.JumpCount = 10
                playerman.y = 500 - playerman.height
            if collide:
                if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                    playerman.isJump = True
                playerman.fall = 0

    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount > 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.4
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.JumpCount = 10
            playerman.isJump = False
    playerman.draw()


    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the scrolling. The platform is at 490 and you scroll down when the player is lower than 450. im assuming that the player is 30px tall from the `playerman = player(40,390,30,30, Blue)`. So that means that for the player to stand on the floor, he would be at 460, which means the screen will scroll.

Now you can rather have the floor scroll too, so when he lands, the floor will push the player up and stop, This does mean you will see more of it, You could also change the threshold from 450 to 470, so the player has to be below the floor to scroll down, but without the floor scrolling, it will stay there so you cant scroll down.

So you can either do the first option or both

Comment: its my first game lmaoo